# Neo4j or Gephi for animating graph over time (ideally making a GIF)?

Tags: neo4j, visualization, gephi

I have a couple hundred nodes linking to one another, a sort of social network with no labels on their relationship yet. I want to make a GIF animation of change overtime, maybe as a screenshot.

What is a software that will help me do this best? I have very basic knowledge of how Gephi works and knows very basic of Neo4j bloom - just inputting cypher code to generate a visualization but not much else.

Is Neo4j friendly for making animation of change of graph over time? (Time increment may be year or a few years; I can make a time index for the visualization). I am still new to this so please advise if it is easier to go with Gephi or other tools. I want something reliable in terms of their position, that I can even take screenshot and animate it as a GIF. I know this can be hard since it might regenerate everytime. Thank you

The nodes move around unexpectedly so it is hard to see change/pattern.

I see that GraphAware Neo4j ChangeFeed - is RETIRED. Also GraphGists look advanced for me.

Comment: If you are any good with Javascript, you can use any of the libraries like visjs to generate a timeline. I did it once upon a time with: https://github.com/tomasonjo/neo4j-hp-viz/blob/main/ui/src/components/Timeline.js

Comment: Thank you for your kind comment. I never used javascript before, only python. I had used processing.js which was in java a long time ago. I will try to learn vis.js this over the next week... I guess because it is browser-based I could just run my code in visual studio and it should work, or do I need anything else?

Comment: Exactly, code in VS and check the visualizations in browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can visualize graph changes over time in [Neo4j Bloom](https://neo4j.com/product/bloom/) using the playback functionality of the [slicer tool](https://neo4j.com/docs/bloom-user-guide/current/bloom-tutorial/slicer/). Here's one I was playing around with (articles and topics):
[image]

Comment: This is what I would like to use! With some struggling I finally was able to get slicer to appear on my screen :) Thank you so much! May I ask what you use to do the gif? I was thinking of just using screenshot and do it manually but maybe you have a better advice... Thanks again!

Comment: Cool - glad you got it working! I used Snagit to screen capture the gif.